# Error while displaying a view sql

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I've created a View with a SQL query:

```
CREATE VIEW rightview
AS 
SELECT data.accounts.login,data.accounts.password,data.customers.right_
FROM data.accounts join data.customers using (id);
```

When i cliick on execute the query, it indicates that the View was created successfully. But when I try to display its columns with this query

```
select * from data.rightview;
```

I got this error:

> Error code 1356, SQL state HY000: View 'data.rightview' references
>   invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of
>   view lack rights to use them

Comment: Like the message say, you are trying to reference tables or columns that does not exists. Double check that the names are correct. Try execute the SELECT query before createing the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO better will be:

```
CREATE VIEW rightview
AS
SELECT acc.login, acc.password, cust.right_
FROM data.accounts acc
LEFT JOIN data.customers cust on acc.id=cust.id
```

if table customers include column ID which is reference to table accounts...

Comment: with the query of Kenda i get a row filled with login and apssword but right is null

Comment: LEFT JOIN use if you have "master" table.
Left join appends table rows and columns to master table. So if you have table A with 2 rows and table B with 2 rows belongs to 1 row from table A, you get together 3 rows. First row wil be A1+B1, second A1+B2 and third only A2+null
On the other hand JOIN is used if you have 2 tables and you need select rows, that are affected in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try using table alias

```
CREATE VIEW rightview
AS 
SELECT account.login,account.password,customer.right_
FROM data.accounts as account join data.customers as customer using (id);
```

and

```
select * from rightview;
```

Comment: Thanks Madhivanan for your answer i can see the the columns of the view but they are empty

Comment: It means that there are no rows that matches with the tables

Comment: how comes?? This is how my tables look like :

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: when i execute Select * from customers two rows are fulled with two other rows in the table accounts 
But the view rightview appears empty. The columns exists but with no rows

Comment: Does the column id have same values for both the tables?

Comment: the id in the table customers is the same customer_id in the table accounts. But the accounts_id in the table customers is null 
Maybe this is the problem

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this one..**

```
CREATE VIEW rightview
AS SELECT a.login,a.password,b.right_
FROM accounts a INNER JOIN customers b
on a.id = b.id;
```

> **then,**

```
select * from rightview;
```

> **will work..**

Answer (score 0):

I got same error. I solved coping all code from original view in the original db and pasted into bkp_db creating other view...